ngx-toastr do not disappear. Angular18
I have following problem. I'm using Angular 18 and ngx-toastr 19.0.0. When I try to use notification in ngOnInit (with 5 sec deley) result is so:
1- notification is rendered immediately
2- after 5 sec progress bar stars and go to the end (as it should)
3- notification didn't disappear even if I click close button.
Any idea what is going on?
export class ConfComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.toastr.info('Message', 'Title', {
        closeButton: true,
        progressBar: true,
        progressAnimation: 'increasing',
        positionClass: 'toast-bottom-left',
        timeOut: 2000
      });
    }, 5000);
  }
}

If I start toastr by some button click it works fine.

i cant reproduce your error. its working for me. can you make an example in stackblitz?

Could be the change detection
Try to inject the ChangeDetectionRef , and detect changes after the info was called
